# Mysql Trigger on multiple column updates

Tags: mysql, triggers

I know how to write a simple trigger

Can anyone tell me whats the best approach to write a trigger in which a new entry is added/updates on subTable if and only any of  col1,coln2,col3....col9 is updated or a new entry is done on mainTable

Answer (score 0):

"[if] a new entry is done on mainTable" is an `INSERT` [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).

As for column values being changed, that's an `UPDATE` trigger.  You can check the old value against the new value like this:

```
 if (col1 != values(col1)) ....
```

If your values can be NULL, be more vigilant.

Hope that helps.